# Finding last character

Tags: c, char

I'm new to C and trying to create a function that check a string and returns the last character.

I get the function to print the correct letter, but I cant figure out how to return it :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char last_chr(char *c);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *text[15];
    strcpy(text, "*find:last;char#");

    last_chr(text);  //debugging

    //printf("last char: %c", last_chr(text));   //not working

    return 0;
}

char last_chr(char *c) {
    char *endchr;
    char result;
    int pos = strlen(c)-1;

    endchr = c[pos];

    //sprintf(result,"%s",endchr);      //"EXEC_BAD_ACCESS"
    putchar(endchr);                    //prints #
    //putc(endchr, result);             //"EXEC_BAD_ACCESS"
    //printf(endchr);                   //"EXEC_BAD_ACCESS"
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `endchr = c[pos];` giving you an error as well?

Comment: that only gives me a warning: "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: Never, ever, ignore a warning. Unless you have a really good reason for it. And even then, fix it. This warning in particular is very dangerous to ignore as you're messing up a pointer. Making it point to random data. Hint: compile with `-Wall -pedantic` if you're using GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char last_chr(char *c);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char text[32];//char *text[15]

    strcpy(text, "*find:last;char#");//length is 17

    printf("last char: %c", last_chr(text));//#

    return 0;
}

char last_chr(char *c) {
    if(c == NULL || *c == '\0') return 0;
    return c[strlen(c)-1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign `result`. You probably mean

```
result = c[pos];
```

instead of `endchr = c[pos];`

`endchr` is a character-pointer instead of a character.